# Make multiple targets in 'all'

Tags: makefile

i'm trying to build a debug and release version of a library with a Makefile and copy those libraries to the relevant build directories, e.g.

```
.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME_DEBUG)
    $(CP) $(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(BUILD_DIR)/debug/$(program_NAME_DEBUG)
    $(RM) $(program_NAME_DEBUG)
    $(RM) $(program_OBJS)
    $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
    $(CP) $(program_NAME_RELEASE) $(BUILD_DIR)/release/$(program_NAME_RELEASE)
    $(RM) $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
    $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

$(program_NAME_DEBUG): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK_DEBUG.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME_DEBUG)

$(program_NAME_RELEASE): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK_RELEASE.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(program_NAME_RELEASE) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
```

The 1st target in all (program_NAME_DEBUG) compiles OK but the 2nd, (program_NAME_RELEASE) produces the following error:

```
libGlam_rel.so
make: libGlam_rel.so: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

`libGlam_rel.so` is the value of `program_NAME_RELEASE`

It doesn't seem to be recognising the 2nd target as it does the 1st?

**EDIT**

finally got this working.

one issue was having src files in multiple dirs, used VPATH to sort this, e.g.

```
# specify dirs other then current dir to search for src files
VPATH = ../../pulse_IO/src ../../../g2/src
```

Added in additional library targets into the platform conditional stuff, e.g.

```
# Platform specific conditional compilation
UNAME := $(shell uname)

TARGET := Glam

ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
# LINUX version
program_NAME := lib$(TARGET).so
program_DEBUG_NAME := lib$(TARGET)_dbg.so
program_RELEASE_NAME := lib$(TARGET)_rel.so
BUILD_DIR = ../build/linux
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME), MINGW32_NT-6.1)
# WINDOWS version
program_NAME := lib$(TARGET).dll
program_DEBUG_NAME := lib$(TARGET)_dbg.dll
program_RELEASE_NAME := lib$(TARGET)_rel.dll
BUILD_DIR = ../build/windows
endif
```

added the new debug and release object files:

```
DEBUG_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/debug/,${program_OBJS})
RELEASE_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/release/,${program_OBJS})
```

set my debug and release CFLAGS:

```
DEBUG_CFLAGS := -fPIC -g -Wall -DDEBUG=1
RELEASE_CFLAGS := -fPIC -O2 -Wall -DDEBUG=0
```

collated all the debug and release compiler options:

```
DEBUG_LINK.c := $(CC) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
RELEASE_LINK.c := $(CC) $(RELEASE_CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

added my new rules to the 'all' target:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: $(program_DEBUG_NAME) $(program_RELEASE_NAME)
```

the rule set looks like this (inc. a replacement for the implicit object file generation):

```
$(program_DEBUG_NAME): $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(DEBUG_LINK.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ -o $(BUILD_DIR)/debug/$@

$(program_RELEASE_NAME): $(RELEASE_OBJS)
    $(RELEASE_LINK.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ -o $(BUILD_DIR)/release/$@

# rule to build object files (replaces implicit rule)
$(BUILD_DIR)/debug/%.o: %.c
    $(DEBUG_LINK.c) $< -c -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/release/%.o: %.c
    $(RELEASE_LINK.c) $< -c -o $@
```

and to finish off I modified clean to deal with all the new files:

```
clean:
    @- $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)/debug/$(program_DEBUG_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    @- $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)/release/$(program_RELEASE_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(RELEASE_OBJS)
```

This works allowing me to produce debug and release versions of my library across linux and windows platforms with a single Makefile, e.g. `$ make -k`

Comment: why? I think I'm using vpath correctly here, i.e. searching for sources *not* targets?

Comment: its fine for a simple makefile and if thats all youre going for then thats ok. you will run into problems if your project starts having files with the same names although different paths

Comment: ah yes - i can see that would be a potential problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. You seem to want different versions of the object files for the two libraries, but there is nothing in this makefile that will provide that.

There are several ways to do it. The cleanest is probably to have two directories:

```
debug_objs/
  ang.o
  naur.o
  gul.o

release_objs/
  ang.o
  naur.o
  gul.o
```

The second-cleanest is to have different file names:

```
  ang_debug.o
  naur_debug.o
  gul_debug.o

  ang_rel.o
  naur_rel.o
  gul_rel.o
```

Either way, you can write rules for `RELEASE_OBJS` and `DEBUG_OBJS` (we can help with that, if need be).

Now look at the library rules:

```
$(program_NAME_DEBUG): $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(LINK_DEBUG.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(DEBUG_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME_DEBUG)

$(program_NAME_RELEASE): $(RELEASE_OBJS)
    $(LINK_RELEASE.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(program_NAME_RELEASE) $(RELEASE_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
```

We can use [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to make them more concise:

```
$(program_NAME_DEBUG): $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(LINK_DEBUG.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ -o $@

$(program_NAME_RELEASE): $(RELEASE_OBJS)
    $(LINK_RELEASE.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ -o $@
```

(We could go a little farther, but let's not push it.)

Now for `all`. We move `$(program_NAME_RELEASE)` into the prerequisite list where it belongs:

```
all: $(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
    $(CP) $(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(BUILD_DIR)/debug/$(program_NAME_DEBUG)
    $(RM) $(program_NAME_DEBUG)
    $(RM) $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(CP) $(program_NAME_RELEASE) $(BUILD_DIR)/release/$(program_NAME_RELEASE)
    $(RM) $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
    $(RM) $(RELEASE_OBJS)
```

But there's no reason to remove the object files, since they can't collide, and Make will delete them anyway if they're intermediate files. And there's no need to `$(CP)` and then `$(RM)` when we can just `mv`. And there's no need to `mv`; if that's where the libraries belong, we can build them there in the first place:

```
all: $(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(program_NAME_RELEASE)

$(program_NAME_DEBUG): $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(LINK_DEBUG.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ -o $(BUILD_DIR)/debug/$@

$(program_NAME_RELEASE): $(RELEASE_OBJS)
    $(LINK_RELEASE.c) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ $^ -o $(BUILD_DIR)/release/$@
```

**EDIT:**
To build the object files (I'll guess that you're using C):

```
OBJS:= ang.o naur.o gul.o
DEBUG_OBJS := $(addprefix debug_objs/,$(OBJS))
RELEASE_OBJS := $(addprefix release_objs/,$(OBJS))

debug_objs/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $< -o $@

release_objs/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

(Just make sure that those directories exist-- you can automate that too, but you're making enough changes for one day.)

Comment: this looks great - i think part of my confusion is that the object files get made automatically and thats not what i want here, as you say, i would like to have two targets that build those object files into two dirs, a debug and a release dir - how do you go about doing that?

Comment: i may leave the conciseness improvements out - to the uninitiated it makes Makefiles impenetrable

Comment: @Hiett, I've thought of an improvement to the library rules, but I don't want to hit you with too much at once...

Comment: @Hiett, let's take it one step at a time. Can you build an object (e.g. `make debug_objs/ang.o`)?

Comment: @Hiett, are you sure? I know makefiles have a harsh learning curve, but this one isn't really all that bad, and I'd be happy to walk you through it...

Comment: had another go after a cup of tea and finally got it working! details added to OP, thanks for guidance...

Answer (score 1):

This change should do it:

```
all: $(program_NAME_DEBUG) $(program_NAME_RELEASE)
```

Otherwise, `make all` fails to make `$(program_NAME_RELEASE)`, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: thanks will try that, but will the removal of the object files happen in the right order, e.g. in between building the debug and release versions of the library?

Comment: this does work in as much as both libraries are built, but because the same object files are used in each case (i.e. they are not deleted in between builds) i'm effectively building the same library twice which isn;t what i'm trying to do

Comment: I see.  Makefiles can be tricky, so let's think this through.  The `$(program_NAME_DEBUG):` target evidently is not building `libGlamdring_rel.so`.  Do you wish that it would?

Comment: hmmm, are the compile flags applied at the linking stage tehn , e.g. the same object files can be used to build a debug and release version?

Comment: with your modification it looks like the same library is produced for bothe debug and release version, i.e. they are exactly the same size, previoulsy when I have built debug and release versions using different Makefiles they haev been different sizes, the release being smaller. This was an attempt to have one Makefile build both versions without me having to modify anything in between compilations